# ActiveX not working with local host in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex

I registered an activeX control (developed in C#.net) through **regasm /codebase**  command. I have a html page which uses this activeX control:

```
<body>
    <OBJECT id="DemoActiveX" classid="clsid:14CBF038-4D43-457e-A5D2-CBED641218C5"></OBJECT>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var obj = document.DemoActiveX;
         alert(obj.SomeMethod());
    </script>
</body>
```

When I run this page from file system **obj.SomeMethod() works** but when I run the page from **localhost** it says that Object doesn't support property or method.

What changes are mandatory there to make it run from local host?

Comment: I am searching for that too!

Answer (score 0):

you need to sign your activex object and it will work.